# how to enable PDO_OCI in whm cPanel

Tags: php, pdo, cpanel, oracle-call-interface, whm

I tried to enable PDO_OCI in whm cPanel through software -> Module insataller -> PHP Pecl but it shows error like

```
WARNING: "pear/PDO_OCI" is deprecated in favor of "channel://http://www.php.net/pdo_oci/ext/pdo_oci" pear/PDO_OCI requires PHP extension "pdo" (version >= 1.0) No valid packages found install failed The PDO_OCI.so object is not in /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525 Tidying /usr/local/lib/php.ini... No changes Tidying /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/php/54/etc/php.ini... No changes
```

Then i tried to install PDO and shows

```
WARNING: "pecl/PDO" is deprecated in favor of "channel://http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/trunk/ext/pdo//ext/PDO" downloading PDO-1.0.3.tgz ... Starting to download PDO-1.0.3.tgz (52,613 bytes) .............done:
```

So please help me how can i enable PDO_OCI in my WHM cPanel.

When trying to print phpinfo() from my server it shows PDO is enabled.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you got that far, you may just need to load the pdo_oci extension in cPanel's PHP configuration:

1. WHM -> Service Configuration -> PHP Configuration Editor
2. Advanced Mode
3. Find the "extension" section and add *pdo_oci.so* to the comma
   separated list Save the PHP configuration
4. Check phpinfo() again - you should see pdo_oci available

If that does not work and you still have issues, you can always build the new (non-pecl) pdo_oci into cPanel's PHP manually as follows:

1. Ensure you have the Basic and Devel Instant Client installed (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/linuxx86-64soft-092277.html)
2. Create (or update) the rawopts file (example: /var/cpanel/easy/apache/rawopts/all_php5) for your PHP version to include this line: *---with-pdo-oci=shared,instantclient,/usr,12.1* (assuming you installed version 12.1 of the Oracle Instant Client using RPM)
3. In our case, the PHP LDAP module was checked in EasyApache, so I had to remove the LDAP module from the instant client install to prevent a conflict during compilation: *rm /usr/include/oracle/12.1/client64/ldap.h*
4. Rebuild your profile in EasyApache
5. If successful, add *pdo_oci.so* to the PHP configuration as outlined above

As noted, these steps are only applicable to cPanel.